# ActiveRecord : database relationship definition in models vs foreign keys definitions in tables setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I was following an online tutorial on ActiveRecord where the instructor writes the following code when defining a table and its relationship:

```
#Setup of the database table
class CreateTimeEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :time_entries do |t|
      t.float :time
      t.belongs_to :customer
      t.belongs_to :employee
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

#Relationship definition in the relevant model
class TimeEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

Aren't those lines redundant ?

```
#in table setup
t.belongs_to :customer
t.belongs_to :employee

#in the relevant model
belongs_to :customer
belongs_to :employee
```

I understood that the lines in the db table setup are here to define foreign keys, how come then that we need to define the relationship in the model as well?
I thought foreign keys were by themselves defining such relationship.

What am I missing here? Can't find any clear answer on the web. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are two completely different methods:

Within migration `belongs_to :parent` only creates `parent_id` column - it is only executed when you run migration. No foreign key is defined here - rails do not believe those are needed. This is just a syntatic sugar for:

```
t.integer :parent_id
```

After migrations are run, all rails know is that your TimeEntry model has `parent_id` column - it has absolutely no other meaning. This is why you have to give it the meaning with `belongs_to` - this method executed in context of ActiveRecord objects will create the association - it will create a method `parent` with all the arel power behind it to fetch referenced object as well as provide some validation and save hooks to make working with the object easier. It is not always necessary to have this defined.

In short, without `belongs_to` you would only be able to call `my_model.parent_id` (provided by `belongs_to` in migration), but not `my_model.parent`

Answer (score 0):

They have different goals. The migartion define de db table and allow create or modify the table. The model define to the Rails framework how to work with db tables.

You must define your models like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_entries
end

class Employe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_entries
end

class TimeEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :employe
end
```

At the migration level, `belongs_to :customer` add a field `customer_id` that relate models.